# Why can't I enter my birthdate on Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I go to change my birthdate on Roblox, but nothing shows up, the dropdowns are just blank with no Month, Day or Year:

[image: Birthdate entry in profile with blank fields]

It also shows me a pop up asking to put in the *Missing Details* to improve the experience, but no matter how many times I put in my age it doesn't save and asks it again.

[image: Missing Information prompt]

Comment: My daughter has the exact same problem. This pop-up keeps appearing on the web and android clients. It never saves. And the birthday can't be edited. It is an under 13 account though, so I wonder if that affects it since I know you can't edit the dates on under age accounts. It is super frustrating though.

Comment: @veroxii U.S. laws dont let accounts of people under 13 to have their birthdays changed

Comment: I'm seeing this too, on like every screen he clicks on. It makes the game borderline unplayable having to enter something in dozens of times an hour.

Comment: The Roblox site makes separate API calls to update these values. If the user is behind parental controls or web filtering, the authentication for these API calls can fail because the authentication isn't applying to the calls somehow (you'll see 403 Forbidden errors in browser dev tools). See this Roblox Dev Forum post for a little more info: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/the-old-missing-information-prompt-doesnt-work-properly/1126021/6

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to quite a few people under the age of 13. After an update the data appeared blank, but the age could not be changed because Roblox does not allow children under 13 to change the age.

- If you are under 13: You can request to show your age, but not change it until your 13th birthday (it unlocks itself)
- If you are over 13: The only thing you can do is report your incident to support

In both cases: https://www.roblox.com/support